# How to create a custom setup wizard

Tags: c#, installation, revit-api

I am trying to create a ADDIN SETUP PROJECT in VS 2022 for Revit. and I had some problems

I want to create a Custom Installation Wizard Where the following actions Should be included.

1. License Agreement (Like img)
2. Choose checkbox for version (Like img)
   Example:  if(cb2019 = true) => location for Directories  "C/ProgramData/Revit/Addin/2019"
   if(cb2020 = true) => location for Directories  "C/ProgramData/Revit/Addin/2020"

Comment: The "visual studio installer" projects are easy to use, but are somewhat limited, and I'm not sure if it supports what you want to do. [Wix](https://wixtoolset.org/) is another installer framework that is *very* flexible, but is somewhat difficult to use.